# Laravel's whereBetween not including date from

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Note: Code should work for postgres and mysql.

I want to query a table by `date_from` and `date_to`. Let's say there is a date range with format: `('d-m-Y')`

**Foo:**

```
[
 {'id': 1, "created_at": "2017-05-20 11:18:00"},
 {'id': 2, "created_at": "2017-05-24 11:38:36"}
]
```

Code:

```
$format = 'd-m-Y';
$df = $request->input('date_from');
$dt = $request->input('date_to');
$date_from = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $df);
$date_to = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $dt);

Foo::whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])->get()->toArray();
```

When I query `date_from = '20-05-2017'` and `date_to = '20-05-2017'`, I see an empty array. I expect to see `20-05-2017` Foo's regardless. If I `date_from = '19-05-2017'` and `date_to = '21-05-2017'`, I see `20-05-2017`'s array.

What's wrong with `whereBetween`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is working as expected. The problem you are encountering is primarily that you are asking for the time between the exact same timestamp. While you are only specifying a specific day and not a time, a time is being included. In this case it is most likely exactly midnight. So `'20-05-2017'` becomes `'20-05-2017 00:00:00'`. In this case there are no times except that exact time which will satisfy your `whereBetween` call.

If you want to get records of a specific date the easiest solution for you would be to use:

```
$query->whereRaw('date(created_at) = ?', [date('Y-m-d')]);
```

If you are looking to query between two *different* dates, your current method will work.

If you want the start time to be the beginning of the day and the end time to be the end of the day you can use Carbon's [modifiers](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers) for this `startOfDay` and `endOfDay`:

```
$date_from = Carbon::parse($request->input('date_from'))->startOfDay();
$date_to = Carbon::parse($request->input('date_to'))->endOfDay();

$result = Foo::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

My startdate and enddate has format **YYYY-mm-dd**

```
$query->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->startdate.' 00:00:00', $request->enddate.' 23:59:59']);
```

Just concatenate time with your date.

Comment: Yes,  this technique really works

Comment: the working technique, rocket

Answer (score 5):

It is working correctly.

Problem is that you are passing in whereBetween date only `Y-m-d` format and laravel is comparing this format with `Y-m-d H:i:s` format of created_at column.

When you are passing only `Y-m-d`, it will be transformed to `Y-m-d 00:00:00`. So your created_at `2017-05-20 11:18:00` is not between `20-05-2017 00:00:00` and `20-05-2017 00:00:00`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I understand. But forgive me, I have to award the person that gives a coded answer as well. Ive given you an upvote, though ;) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but you can now use `this`

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
```

`in place` of

```
->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from)
->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works with a specific date to another, no days increment.

Answer (score 1):

`createFromFormat` creates the date from the given input and replaces the missing time with your current time. So use `parse` instead, you don't even need to specify the form. Secondly you're using `whereBetween` which checks the complete timestamp and not just the date. You're first row `2017-05-20 11:18:00` is outside the range of dates, therefore it won't return the value. You need to use `whereDate` to check for items based on date alone while ignoring the time.

```
$date_from = Carbon::parse($request->input('date_from'));
$date_to = Carbon::parse($request->input('date_to'));

$result = Foo::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```